# Android work profile app: how to push and pull data

Tags: android, adb, android-work-profile

I have workprofile app installed, and the location of the data can be access programmatically using `getExternalFilesDir("logs")` which, results in storage location as `/storage/emulated/11/Android/data/com.example.workprofile/files/logs`.

I would like to know how to push data to logs folder and pull using `adb`.

Comment: is the answer below helping?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to copy the file called `data.log`. The following commands will push the file into a temporary folder

```
adb shell push data.log /data/local/tmp
```

and then you can copy it into your app's private area:

```
adb shell run-as com.example.workprofile cp /data/local/tmp/data.log /data/data/com.example.workprofile/files/logs/data.log
```

If you want to pull the file you can do the opposite but you have to make sure that the file you want to copy already exists in the `/data/local/tmp` folder to workaround the permission deny issue (if the file does not exist).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Above methods works for path `/data/data/com....` however, doesnt work for App on workprofile as different sdcard paths say `/storage/emulated/11/Android/data/...`  and results in `permission denied`

Comment: This only works on Android 11 (and beyond) when the application has `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions. If not, the app cannot access `/data/local/tmp` nor any other (temporary) directory I know of. So the file can be pushed just fine, but it can't be seen / accessed by the work profile user.